# How do I handle files with spaces in the classpath in MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, spaces

I try to build JAR with a `Class-Path` element in the `MANIFEST.MF`. I get the elements of the class path from an outside source (Maven in my case). Since the paths are absolute and beyond my control, they can contain weird characters like spaces.

Since spaces are used to separate items in the class path, this path doesn't work:

```
Class-Path: C:\User\Some Odd Name\project\target\project-1.0.0.jar
```

How can I escape / encode odd characters / whitespace in items of the classpath in the JAR Manifest?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Elements in the `Class-Path` element are URLs, so the usual escaping rules apply (and you should use forward slashes as well):

```
Class-Path: /C:/User/Some%20Odd%20Name/project/target/project-1.0.0.jar
```

Note: The initial slash is necessary since `C` is not a valid network protocol (like `http` or `ftp`). If you were pedantic, it should be `file:///C:/...`

Comment: I didn't know they are URLs.  This is very helpful to me, as I need to split the list of URLs.  I was wondering what to do about spaces in paths / JAR file names... now I know I can ignore.  They will be represented using URL entities, e.g., (space) -> `%20`

Comment: Good, however I found that for this kind of absolute path, also I had to include a '/' before the drive letter:

`Class-Path: /C:/User/Some%20Odd%20Name/project/target/project-1.0.0.jar`

Comment: @R.D.Alkire Correct since `C` is not a valid network protocol unlike, say `http` or `ftp`. To be very correct, it should be `file:/C:/...` but one could argue that the context (the manifest file) is a file, so the base URL is alreay `file://...` Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For me the caret character was the only way to successfully escape the withespace in a **Windows** classpath:

```
Class-Path: C:\User\Some^ Odd^ Name\project\target\project-1.0.0.jar
```

Comment: That should not work. Java doesn't invoke CMD.EXE to parse the MANIFEST.MF file...